# Each row of the input matrix needs to contain at least one non-zero entry

Tags: r, memory, lda, topic-modeling

I have this issue when I run this chunk of code

```
text_lda <- LDA(text_dtm, k = 2, method = "VEM", control = NULL)
```

I have the next mistake **"Each row of the input matrix needs to contain at least one non-zero entry"**

Then I tried to solve this with these lines

```
row_total = apply(text_dtm, 1, sum)
empty.rows <- text_dtm[rowTotals == 0, ]$dimnames[1][[1]]
```

But I got the next issue

> cannot allocate vector of size 3890.8 GB

This is the size of my DTM:

```
DocumentTermMatrix documents: 1968850, terms: 265238
Non-/sparse entries: 29766814/522184069486
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 4000
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

Comment: The problem is that `apply` converts your sparse matrix to a dense matrix , hence memory errors. You could see if there is a sparse matrix `rowSums` method instead of `apply`

Comment: How did you generate the dtm? What package did you use?

Comment: text_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(text_corpus_clean,control = list(tolower=TRUE,removePunctuation = TRUE, removeNumbers= TRUE,stopwords = TRUE,sparse=TRUE))

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
empty.rows <- text_dtm[rowTotals == 0, ]$dimnames[1][[1]] 
corpus_new <- corpus[-as.numeric(empty.rows)]
```

Or use `tm` to generate the dtm and then:

```
ui = unique(text_dtm$i)
text_dtm.new = text_dtm[ui,]
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d recommend using a `dgCMatrix` class for your DTM. It ships with R as part of the widely-used `Matrix` package, works with `topicmodels::LDA` and many other NLP packages (`textmineR`, `text2vec`, `tidytext`, etc.), has methods that let you work with it as if it was a dense matrix.

```
library(tm)
library(topicmodels)
library(Matrix)

# grab a character vector of text. Your source may be different
text <- textmineR::nih_sample$ABSTRACT_TEXT

text_corpus <- SimpleCorpus(VectorSource(text))

text_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(text_corpus,
                               control = list(tolower=TRUE,
                                              removePunctuation = TRUE, 
                                              removeNumbers= TRUE,
                                              stopwords = TRUE,
                                              sparse=TRUE))

text_dtm2 <- cast_sparse(text_dtm)

text_dtm2 <- Matrix::sparseMatrix(i=text_dtm$i, 
                                  j=text_dtm$j,
                                  x=text_dtm$v, 
                                  dims=c(text_dtm$nrow, text_dtm$ncol), 
                                  dimnames = text_dtm$dimnames)

doc_lengths <- Matrix::rowSums(text_dtm2)

text_dtm3 <- text_dtm2[doc_lengths > 0, ]

text_lda <- LDA(text_dtm3,  k = 2, method = "VEM", control = NULL)
```

Comment: I have the next mistake with this text_dtm2 <- cast_sparse(text_dtm)   "no applicable method for 'ungroup' applied to an object of class "c('DocumentTermMatrix', 'simple_triplet_matrix')"

Comment: I made this m <-  Matrix::sparseMatrix(i=text_dtm$i, 
                           j=text_dtm$j, 
                           x=text_dtm$v, 
                           dims=c(text_dtm$nrow, text_dtm$ncol),
                           dimnames = text_dtm$dimnames) and then I tried this text_dtm2 <- cast_sparse(text_dtm) but is not working

Comment: That of course should work. But can I ask you to share your code for making text_dtm? I'd like to see for myself why cast_sparse wouldn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Yes of course! text_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(text_corpus_clean,control = list(tolower=TRUE,removePunctuation = TRUE, removeNumbers= TRUE,stopwords = TRUE,sparse=TRUE))

Comment: Thank you. I’ll look tonight then update my answer so that it works.

Comment: Code above should work in its entirety now. Turns out cast_sparse only works for an object that follows from unnest_tokens.